# cannot use buffer-local variables after defining them

Tags: variables, buffer-local, local-variables

I'm trying to define a buffer-local variable inside a function using `setq-local` in a function
here is the function definition:

```lisp
(defun set-buffer-local-variable ()
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*my-buffer*")
        (erase-buffer)
        (setq-local m-buffer-local-variable 0)
        (print (format "buffer local value: %s" m-buffer-local-variable)) ;; prints 0
        (insert "some content")))
```

`print` in the function works as expected but when trying to access the variable from
other functions (interactive or not ) or from `eval-expression` I get `void variable` error.

I don't know much about elisp but here are some relevant info that I think might help:

1. emacs version: emacs29.0.92
2. `lexical-binding` is set to `nil`
3. `enable-local-variables` is set to `t`

I tried using `make-local-variable` with no success.

Comment: `emacs version: emacs29.0.92` -- you should update to Emacs 29.1 rather than continuing to run the pretest version.  (Not that it will have any bearing on this question, but you should still do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU Emacs 28.1 (which should not make any difference) started with `emacs -Q` I defined the following functions in the `*scratch*` buffer:

```el
(defun set-buffer-local-variable ()
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*my-buffer*")
    (erase-buffer)
    (setq-local m-buffer-local-variable 0)
    (print (format "buffer local value: %s" m-buffer-local-variable)) ;; prints 0
    (insert "some content")))


(defun access-buffer-local-variable ()
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*my-buffer*")
    (print (format "buffer local value: %s" m-buffer-local-variable)) ;; prints 0
    (insert "some content")))
```

First I run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-buffer-local-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> and afterwards I run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `access-buffer-local-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Both times I get the answer `"buffer local value: 0"`. So everything is like expected.

Note also that `enable-local-variable` is about file-local variables. This is related to buffer-local variables but it is not the same. The Setting of `enable-local-variable` does not influence the behavior of buffer local variables.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. this works just fine but not my actual code, I might be to some mistake I made in code not to buffer-local-variables.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, since you `setq` the variable `m-buffer-local-variable`, that's the variable you want to print - instead you are trying to print a different (and undefined) variable `mitmp-request-id`.

Assuming you change the variable to print to `m-buffer-local-variable` instead, then when you call the function, e.g. with `M-: (set-buffer-local-variable)`, it will create `*my-buffer*` if necessary and define `m-buffer-local-variable` as a buffer-local variable *in that buffer*. So if you switch to that buffer with `C-x b *my-buffer*`and ask for the value of the variable with e.g. `C-h v m-buffer-local-variable`, it will tell you its value is 0. But if you do the same thing in any *other* buffer, then it will be undefined. That's exactly how a buffer-local variable is supposed to behave.

Comment: sorry about, the variable I wanted to print is `m-buffer-local-variable` as it is the one defined locally.

Comment: as for the second part of the comment, I did exactly that and I still didn't have the buffer local to the buffer, I checked with `(local-variable-p m-buffer-local-variable )` and it returns `nil`

Comment: I can run `setq-local` and define the variable in the buffer, this works fine. but I don't know why it won't work inside the function.

Comment: @ntriisii: `(local-variable-p 'm-buffer-local-variable)` otherwise you're asking about a variable name stored in the value of `m-buffer-local-variable`.   I ran your code and, in `*my-buffer*`, `describe-variable` tells me `m-buffer-local-variable’s value is 0.  Local in buffer *my-buffer*; globally void`, which is what I'd expect.

Comment: ok, I tried both sorry `(local-variable-p 'm-buffer-local-variable)` gave me nil and `(local-variable-p m-buffer-local-variable )` gave me `void-variable` error.

Comment: anyway, thanks for your help. according to the answer below I think I made some mistake in my code which result in not being able to access the variable.

Comment: Hi Nick, you actually answered the question. Nevertheless, I added a community answer which should be straight forward to reproduce (@ntriisii did it and accepted it). To compensate for your potential point losses I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @ntriisii I would assume that you either had a typo for the variable name in part of your code, or else your code was not checking the variable in the *same buffer* in which you'd set it.  Either of those would produce that result.

Comment: @Tobias: thanks for posting the answer. I suspect that the OP was trying to get the value of the variable in the wrong buffer and getting `nil`, instead of switching to `*my-buffer*`, but it's not entirely clear. So having the reporting function *also* switch to the correct buffer before retrieving the value was a good idea. But I still think that the OP should puzzle it out with their own implementation and "by hand" so to speak: that's part of the learning experience that will come in useful for them in the future.

Comment: Try it now: I added the explicit switching to the correct buffer instructions which I *think* is what you were missing.

Comment: thanks you all for your help. the problem was that I was checking for a wrong `major-mode` to be set after defining the variable. so each time I run the function the `major-mode` changes and it erases my buffer-local variables (don't know if this the expected behaviour or what).

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. If you are still having problems maybe ask a new question and add all the relevant details.